# Is it possible to link slides via google slides api?

Tags: google-slides-api

As specified [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7009814), it is possible to "link" slides from another presentation similar to how you link charts from spreadsheets. Is this possible to do via the google slides api?

Comment: Hello @EthanYidong, would you providing more insight into your issue? Cheers!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/presentation#insertslideinsertionindex,-slide,-linkingmode